# installing docker

Tags: docker

Hello all I am running into a problem installing docker to ubuntu
I cannot start docker daemon even as a root user
here is the error I am getting:

```
INFO[2020-12-18T15:31:10.428736900Z] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
INFO[2020-12-18T15:31:10.428746900Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
DEBU[2020-12-18T15:31:10.431359000Z] received signal                               signal=terminated
DEBU[2020-12-18T15:31:10.438869400Z] sd notification                               error="<nil>" notified=false state="STOPPING=1"
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
```

Also

```
root@COBLBHG01:/usr/bin# lsmod | grep nf_nat
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1657 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's your OS version and how did you install docker?

Comment: Hello Dan it is Ubuntu 18.04.5 and I followed the steps here to install docker using the repository https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: can you add to your question output of `lsmod | grep nf_nat`?

Comment: @RomanK done I attached it above

Comment: Are you using WSL v1?

Comment: @RomanK yes I have upgraded it and docker daemon finally worked :)

Comment: If the below answers your question, please select it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of the `lsmod` I am assuming you are using the WSL v1 on Windows. It is a simulation of Linux and is not using Linux kernel.

Microsoft have released WSLv2 which runs full linux system inside virtual machine.
Refer to [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) on how to upgrade to WSLv2.